# C# MongoDB Driver - How to use UpdateDefinitionBuilder?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I looked up a way to work with mongodb's `UpdateDefinitionBuilders` but the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/driver/definitions/#update-definition-builder) doesn't really show much...

I need to be able to dynamically build my update queries, so I thought about doing it like this:

```
var update = Builders<Product>.Update;

update.Set("add A update");

if ()
    update.Set("add X update");
else
    update.Set("add Y update");

update.Set("add B update");

if ()
    update.Set("add Z update");
else
    update.Set("add P update");

Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

But it gives a compilation error:

`cannot convert from UpdateDefinitionBuilder UpdateDefinition`

I looked, but couldn't find, a solution how to works with this `UpdateDefinitionBuilders`

Can someone please give a code sample of how to use this class?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you need to simply update multiple properties you can call `Set` on update builder and then make subsequent call to `Set` extension methods. You can either use lambda expression or property name.

```
var update = Builders<Product>.Update
    .Set(p => Name, "Name value")
    .Set(p => Description, "Description value");

collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

If you want conditionally update some properties you should create a collection of the updates and then combine them:

```
var update = Builders<Product>.Update;
var updates = new List<UpdateDefinition<Product>>();

updates.Add(update.Set("propertyA", "add A update"));

if ()
    updates.Add(update.Set("propertyX", "add X update"));
else
    updates.Add(update.Set("propertyY", "add Y update"));

updates.Add(update.Set(p => p.PropertyB, "add B update"));

if ()
    updates.Add(update.Set(p => p.PropertyZ, "add Z update"));
else
    updates.Add(update.Set(p => p.PropertyP, "add P update"));

Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update.Combine(updates), updateOptions);
```

Comment: In the very latest version of the library, .Set() returns UpdateDefinition, not UpdateDefinitionBuilder, so it's not possible to chain it with another .Set(). Did id change or am I missing something? Thanks...

Comment: @VáclavMikeska nothing has changed around it in latest version, there's an extension method https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/UpdateDefinitionBuilder.cs#L684-L688 for the UpdateDefinition. Make sure to invoke extension method on subsequent calls.

Comment: perfect solution :)